# Angular: Map template-data to other presentation

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to show data but also map the values to another presentation (can include HTML-entities).

Here same sample.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9l1vff

vals has the data.
getVal does the mapping.

Is there a way to do this in the template (without having a big ngIf or creating a component for every special value)?

The mapping is completely view-related and displaying the HTML does not work too (think I would need the HTML-sanizizer but I do not like that idea).

Whats the most efficient strategy here?

Answer (score 0):

You can try pure `pipe` that is called only when reference on input was changed and you can store it outside of your component.
In your example `getVal` is called on every Change detection cycle.
To sanitize trusted HTML - just create another pipe and chain them.